# Diffie-Hellman private key recover with non-prime modulus

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic, elgamal-encryption

Say we have a classic Diffie-Hellman key exchange. We have the following parameters of a public key:

```
p,g,y
```

Where $p$ is the modulus, $g$ is the base, $y$ is the public key, and $x$ is the private key in the following equation:

$y = g^x \bmod p$

It happens that the modulus is a composite number, which can be factored into primes.

How can someone find $x$, thus solving in the discrete logarith problem (DLP), by factorizing the modulus into primes, and solving the smaller DLP's with the primes, then combining them with chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Hint: you have found $x_i$ with $g^{x_i} \bmod p_i = y \bmod p_i=g^x \bmod p_i$. Using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), what's a large divisor $d_i$ of $x-x_i$? Are these $d_i$ coprime, which would be ideal to apply the CRT? Can we workaround that issue and find a suitable $x$ (or the lowest positive one)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. What role does Fermat's little theorem play in finding x after solving the discrete log problems? I know that all the primes for the factoring of p is coprime.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I'm fairly new to this, and I'm a bit unsure how to implement it. From here on, what should I calculate, and what should I pass to CRT. I saw an implementation somewhere else (https://github.com/pberba/ctf-solutions/blob/master/20180913_sect/matryoskal/matry.sage) which seemed to work fine, but when I plot my parameters the correct places, _h = y, etc., then crt returns an error saying something alike that gcd(m,n) does not divide a, b. These are parameters of sage's own crt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start by finding the factorization of $p$ as $\prod p_i$; then find the $x_i$ with $g^{x_i}\equiv y\pmod{p_i}$ using an auxiliary algorithm to solve the DLP, perhaps [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) and/or [Pohlig-Helman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm).

I'll assume that the $p_i$ are distinct, which was the case in the [original question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/67093/5). They thus are coprime, and by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) $g^x\equiv y\pmod p$ is equivalent to $\forall i, g^x\equiv y\pmod{p_i}$.

Fermat's little theorem tells us that $g^{p_i-1}\equiv1\pmod{p_i}$, since $p_i$ is a prime not dividing $g$. Therefore, $g^x\equiv g^{x\bmod(p_i-1)}\pmod{p_i}$. Therefore it is sufficient to find $x$ such that $\forall i,x\equiv x_i\pmod{p_i-1}$ (see final section for a better alternative).

Problem is, the moduli $m_i=p_i-1$ are not coprime: for a start, they all are divisible by $2$. That prevents a different use of the regular CRT to find $x$. We need to reduce the $m_i$ in order to make them coprime, while leaving their Least Common Multiple unchanged.

Assuming that we can fully factor the $m_i$: we collect every prime $q_j$ in these factorizations, and find it's maximal multiplicity $k_j$ (that is the maximal $k_j$ so that $q_j^{k_j}$ divides at least one of the $m_i$). Then for each $q_j$, we select one (of possibly several) $m_i$ that $q_j^{k_j}$ divides, and we divide each *other* $m_i$ by $q_j$ as many times as possible.
Note 1: Each time we divide an $m_i$ by $q_j^{k_{j,i}}$, we can check that $x_i\equiv x_j\pmod{q_j^{k_{k,j}}}$, and otherwise conclude that there is no solution.
Note 2: We can avoid full factorization of the $m_i$ and use Greatest Common Divisor computations, but that's slightly involved; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104435/35016).

If $x\equiv x_i\pmod{p_i-1}$, then $x\equiv x_i\pmod{m_i}$ holds for the reduced $m_i$. The converse holds if we made the checks in note 1. We can now find a suitable $x$ using the regular CRT, requiring coprime $m_i$. We do not need to recompute the $x_i$, but we can reduce them modulo $m_i$.

If we did not perform the checks in note 1, we need a final check that $g^x\equiv y\pmod p$.

---

Another issue is that $x\equiv x_i\pmod{p_i-1}$ is a sufficient, but not necessary condition for $g^x\equiv g^{x_i}\pmod{p_i}$ to hold. Thus, the CRT applied as above can find an $x$ that's needlessly larger than needed. A solution to this is to initialize $m_i$ with the order of $g$ modulo $p_i$, that is the smallest positive $m_i$ with $g^{m_i}\equiv1\pmod{p_i}$. That's some divisor of $p_i-1$, not always $p_i-1$ itself.

Comment: Thanks for you help @fgrieu. Sorry for no formatting in the following scenario. So, if I understands it correctly, I can factor mi to other primes, and then find a smaller mi, which is coprime, and thus applicable to CRT. But I'm not quite sure how I do that. I'm a bit confused by your notation as I am fairly new to this. Lets take an example, where pi - 1 = 18072481203497442510. This can be factored to 2 · 3^2 · 5 · 29 · 109 · 727 · 1583 · 4327 · 12757. But at this point, it didn't understand the rest. What is next step to finding the smaller mi?

Comment: Also, when I have found all smaller mi. Can I use them with my xi from the previous calculations, or do I have to solve DLP for them all again with my new mi? I hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks man, finally got it! I wish I could upvote x1000